# Script for open image in new window not working

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using this code to open an image in a new window, but i can't get it to work. What is wrong?

```
echo "
<td align='center'>
<a href='images/spasergjengen/" . $row['Grad'] . "'  target='_blank'>
  <img src='images/spasergjengen/" . $row['Grad'] . "' width='125' height='150' 
  title='Spasergjengen' alt='Spasergjengen' />
</a>
<br>
<button onclick='myFunction" . $row['MedlemId'] . "'()'>Se Bilde</button>
<script>
   function myFunction" . $row['MedlemId'] . "'() {     
   window.open('images/spasergjengen/" . $row['Grad'] . "', '_blank',
  'toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes
  ,top=200,left=300,width=750,height=565'); } 
</script>
</td>
";
```

Comment: Typo: On the first line you have an extra quote: `"'()'` should be `"()'`

Comment: And on the 2nd line: `"'()` should be `"()`

Comment: You should see these if you use `View Source` in the browser.

Comment: You should also be getting syntax errors in the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

[Tested]

```
<?php  echo "<td align='center'><a href='images/spasergjengen/" . $row['Grad'] . "'  target='_blank'><img src='images/spasergjengen/" . $row['Grad'] . "' width='125' height='150' title='Spasergjengen' alt='Spasergjengen' /></a><br><button onclick='myFunction" . $row['MedlemId'] . "()'>Se Bilde</button>
<script> function myFunction" . $row['MedlemId'] . "() {     window.open('images/spasergjengen/" . $row['Grad'] . ",_blank', 'toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=200,left=300,width=750,height=565'); } </script></td>";
?>
```